# Find the transformation $P$ that satisfies:

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

$$\displaystyle\min_{\mathbf{P}} \text{trace}(\mathbf{APP^HA^H}) \quad{} \text{subject to} \quad{} \text{trace}(\mathbf{(I-P)(I-P)^H})=\alpha, \alpha \geq0$$ $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix, $A$ is $L\times K, K>L$ and $P$ is $K \times K$, $\alpha$ is known and is fixed to a value. For example, if $P$ is a projection that projects onto $N(A)$, $AP=0$ which satisfies the objective function, and $\alpha = L$ in this case. However my objective is not to force $AP$ to zero, hoping that $\alpha$ is less than $L$, also $\alpha$ does not have to be an integer and $P$ does not have to be a projection.
Is this solvable? and if so, any directions on how to solve it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you replace $P$ by $I-P$, you can write the above as $\min \{ \|A(P+I)\|^2 \, | \,  \|P\|_F^2 = \alpha \}$. What norm is the objective?

Comment: @copper.hat How did you get $A(P+I)$?. I understand $\text{trace}(PP^H)=\|P\|_F^2$, I could also write the constraint as $\|I-P\|_F^2)=\alpha$ directly. Also how would this replacement help?

Comment: @copper.hat norm in the objective function is the frobenius norm.

Comment: It was just an alternative view point, in case that triggered another's answer. You may want to look at the computations involved in trust-region methods, as these have similar characteristics.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you, I will give it a look.

Comment: Seems relevant: Forsythe & Golub, "On the stationary values of a second-degree polynomial on the
unit sphere", J. Soc. Indust. Appl. Math., 13 (1965), pp. 1050-1068. Probably a lot more recent relevant stuff. I got this from an 1982 paper by D. Sorensen.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the paper, I will surely take a look at that.

Comment: Any progress? ${}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142347/find-the-transformation-p-that-minimizes-the-following

Comment: Cool! The answer is very similar to trust region method calculations (like Levenberg Marquardt).